# Parser CDATA xml

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Having an XML with an embedded XML inside a `[CDATA]` any idea how can we parser that xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<a>
    <b>
        <c>
            <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><bigXML>]]>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

I cannot use regex/replace over the value of `c` since the embedded XML is an xml of `250mb` size, and if I try ant of those operators I got a `Java Heap Out of memory`.

Comment: Assuming your unused tags are those that can be replaced with empty space, you can end up with required tags.

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand what do you mean

Comment: I mean string.replace("<a>","");I mean string.replace("<b>",""); etc, and so on until you leave with the only xml you need

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). Jsoup is actually an html parser, but is also capable of parsing xml. It is quite intuitive and once you are familiar with the [selector syntax](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) it is very easy to use. You can parse the content of your cdata to a [CDataNode](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/CDataNode.html) and use the built-in methods to get what you need.

Maven dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.14.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Modified your very simplified xml given above to have an example to play around with:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.CDataNode;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class TestJavaClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n"
                + "<axx>\n"
                + "    <bxx>\n"
                + "        <cxx>\n"
                + "            <![CDATA["
                + "                     <?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n"
                + "                         <catalog>\n"
                + "                             <book id=\"bk101\">\n"
                + "                                 <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>\n"
                + "                                 <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>\n"
                + "                                 <genre>Computer</genre>\n"
                + "                                 <price>44.95</price>\n"
                + "                                 <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>\n"
                + "                                 <description>An in-depth look at creating applications \n"
                + "                                 with XML.</description>\n"
                + "                             </book>\n"
                + "                             <book id=\"bk102\">\n"
                + "                                 <author>Ralls, Kim</author>\n"
                + "                                 <title>Midnight Rain</title>\n"
                + "                                 <genre>Fantasy</genre>\n"
                + "                                 <price>5.95</price>\n"
                + "                                 <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>\n"
                + "                                 <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, \n"
                + "                                 an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen \n"
                + "                                 of the world.</description>\n"
                + "                             </book>"
                + "                         </catalog>"
                + "                 ]]>\n"
                + "        </cxx>\n"
                + "    </bxx>\n"
                + "</axx>\n";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml, "", Parser.xmlParser());
        CDataNode cdata = (CDataNode) doc.selectFirst("cxx").childNode(1);

        Document cdataDoc = Jsoup.parse(cdata.text(),"", Parser.xmlParser());
        Elements authors = cdataDoc.select("book author");
        authors.forEach(aut -> {
            System.out.println(aut.text());
        });
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Gambardella, Matthew
Ralls, Kim
```

**EDIT**

Working with large files might end up in OOM exception. I haven't tried it yet but [acording to this post](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/339) Jsoup has an implemented stream reader to work with large files. Try the overloded parse method which accepts an InputStream if you are facing out of memory errors:

```
public static org.jsoup.nodes.Document parse(@Nullable java.io.InputStream in,
                                         String charsetName,
                                         String baseUri,
                                         org.jsoup.parser.Parser parser)
```

so in the above case something like:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("path to your xml file"));
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(in, "UTF-8", "", Parser.xmlParser());
....
```

Comment: the cdata xml is quote bug(250mb) probably I will need also to use VDT or any other streaming xml parser. Do you know if that Jsoup is working in Streaming or load the whole file in memory?

Comment: @paul See my edit if it helps.